# How to estimate and compare operating costs of gas vs electric furnace?

Tags: electrical, furnace, natural-gas, cost-effective

My home has an old electric, central furnace. All of my neighbors are on natural gas. I pay 5-6 times as much as they do on my heating bills during winter months.

I can either convert my home to natural gas or install an electric heat pump. Air conditioning is not at all important where I live, so considered an insignificant part of the math.

Current rates are:

- $0.34 per therm, for natural gas
- $0.14 per kilowatt hour for electricity

As my electric bills are so high, I need to buy the most efficient equipment possible. Upfront costs will be $8-10k regardless of whether I put in a gas or electric furnace.

Based on current rates, what equipment specs and math are needed to estimate the monthly cost of a natural gas furnace vs an electric heat pump?

Update:

Climate average lows in winter:
Oct: 29°F
Nov: 18°F
Dec: 11°F
Jan: 11°F
Feb: 16°F
Mar: 20°F
Apr: 24°F
May: 33°F

I learned my state offers mail in rebates of $200-375 for installing gas furnaces and a $2000 tax credit for electric heat pumps. Is that indicative of lower costs?

Comment: Knowing the insulation of the house is important also, wondering if your neighbours have good insulation and you don't.

Comment: @crip659 I am also working on adding insulation, replacing windows with more efficient ones, etc.

Comment: The new upgrades of insulation/windows will probably do more to lessen  your cost of heating, than the type of heating system you buy.  Check with locals for any rebates for upgrades.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a TCO (total cost of ownership) calculation - those are notoriously complicated. You can get closer to an operational cost by converting your "therm" and "kWh" to BTU or another unit of heat energy, these are directly comparable and depend on the efficiency and capabilities of the equipment.

Comment: Are you in the U.S.? Which state? Many states offer rebates for different types of equipment which will affect the answers. Your climate also makes a much bigger impact on the cost to operate a heat pump than a natural gas furnace.

Comment: In the UK, all new builds *must* be electric. Gas is being outlawed, for cost & 'green' reasons. Heat pumps these days are very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Heat pumps usually supply air conditioning too so they would be part of the equation. The fact that your neighbors all have converted to a gas furnace should tell you something, maybe that gas is the way to go. your neighbors are a reliable source of information, much more than trying to do the math on a bunch of assumed variables. You didn't state where you live and that's important. If you're in a very cold area, heat pumps might not provide all the heat you need where as a furnace would. Heat pimps usually have a shorter life span because they are used year round where a separate AC and furnace split the seasons.  As far as equipment specs, you'd have to get them from different manufacturers and they will differ greatly. you'd also need to know the R value of your insulation. Check around and see what the local vendors in your area are recommending. If you get the specs and know your R value you'll need multi-variable calculus and differential equations to answer your question.. (just kidding)

I spend a lot of time in Chicago,Il and Miami,Fl. There are gas furnaces in Chicago and heat pumps in Miami. Older units in Florida are electric strip heaters and their cost to operate is through the roof. Luckily, we don't need them much.

Comment: I'm assuming the gas was installed back in the 1970s when the neighborhood was put in, so I don't know that's the best way to decide based on what neighbors are doing. Is there no simple value, telling me "this uses X Watts per hour" and "this uses Y Therms per hour" to make the comparison?

Comment: Average low temperature in January is:  11 °F, Record low: −20 °F.

Comment: @Village Those variables would be different for each size unit and would also be different based on efficiency ratings and manufactures.  What you're asking is like asking "what's the miles per gallon for a car?"

Comment: Suppose I'm looking at the same manufacturer even, similar product on the outside, just internals they change for gas or electric.

Comment: @Village  Then they should specify the those numbers for the product/ model number.  Usually neighborhoods/subdivisions stick with the same type of heating/cooling when they're built. the changes come after the first units get replaced. Talk to them.... I think it's your best answer.

Comment: The neighbors were putting in gas furnaces back before heat pumps worked very well.  It's a different situation today, both with the technology and the non-financial cost of fossil fuel addiction.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Generally speaking, if someone isn't gung ho about climate change mitigation, they aren't going to be convinced easily, if at all, about *the non-financial cost of fossil fuel addiction*. But $ works for most people. Show them that they'll save $1,000 a year and pay for a $4,000 more expensive system (making up numbers) in 4 years that is expected to last 10 years or more, and they'll be sold.

Comment: (And they may be not convinced because they don't believe it is happening/human caused, or simply because they don't care because it isn't their direct problem. The reason really doesn't matter. The solution is to make it worthwhile ($) to do something that happens to help anyway. Similarly, don't try to force electric cars based on "better for the environment", make them better because of overall total cost of ownership and/or fast/fun to drive.)

Comment: @manassehkatz you don't need to believe in climate change, just peak oil and oil wars.  The cure is the same.   Vast fields of oil and gas were recently discovered in, well, actually, roughly the rectangle of Kharkiv, Severodonetsk, Donetsk, Popasna, and Dnipro.   So if Ukraine joins the EU, who need Russia?

Comment: I have a heat pump with gas auxiliary heat, I opted out of the resistance heat.  That was put in about 15 years ago. So far it has been trouble free.  I went through the calculations and the heat pump was the cheapest to operate but then electricity keeps going up and it is now cheaper to use gas to heat. The switchover was simply pushing a button on the stat turning on emergency heat (gas) what a dr0p in energy cost. I am located in Northern Michigan.